# Get a proper report phpUnit

Tags: phpunit, report

Is there a way to get propper logs from a phpUnit test?, In the help manual there are a few options

```
  --log-junit <file>        Log test execution in JUnit XML format to file.
  --log-tap <file>          Log test execution in TAP format to file.
  --log-json <file>         Log test execution in JSON format.

  --coverage-clover <file>  Generate code coverage report in Clover XML format.
  --coverage-html <dir>     Generate code coverage report in HTML format.
  --coverage-php <file>     Serialize PHP_CodeCoverage object to file.
  --coverage-text=<file>    Generate code coverage report in text format.

  --testdox-html <file>     Write agile documentation in HTML format to file.
  --testdox-text <file>     Write agile documentation in Text format to file.
```

Now, I get the --coverage-html /tmp/report to work and it generates a nice html report, but it's empty. how do I fill it with data about the test? because if I understand it correctly the coverage-html just create a template for the information to be shown.